# Twilio Channel - SMS 60200 Invalid parameter error (400 bad request)

Tags: twilio-api, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I'm getting a "400 - Bad Request" error with Twilio API, but couldn't find the reason.

Here's my request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Verifications' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'Channel=sms' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+44xxxxxxxxxx'
```

I'm getting the response:

```json
{
    "code": 60200,
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200",
    "status": 400
}
```

The response includes a `RequestID` header, but in the Twilio portal there is no way to lookup errors by `RequestID`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not following the product documentation example listed below (which works):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api

```
curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications \
--data-urlencode "To=+15017122661" \
--data-urlencode "Channel=sms" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, what's the difference? Tried in the above format as well and same error message.

Comment: 2nd one works for me without any issues. So it sounds like based on the 4xx error, something wrong with the client side request. I am running cURL 7.64.1.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using the `SERVICE_SID` instead of `ACCOUNT_SID`. Here is what my code looks like

```
import twilio from "twilio";

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
...
const { sid } = await client.verify.services.create({
      friendlyName: "My First Verify Service",
    });

const response = await client.verify.services(sid).verifications.create({
      to,
      channel: "call", // sms, call, or email
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error message even with correct parameters. I was using the account SID in the request URL, when it should be the service SID for the Verify service that was created.

Using the account SID in the url resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue, it appears to be some confusion in the twilio docs, however I did found a place in their docs that show the right way to set this up.

from the official docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/quickstarts/node-express

The solution was to use the `serviceSid` and NOT the `accountSid` as it might suggested in some parts of the docs.

in the code it should look like this:

```
client.verify.v2.services(SERVICE_SID)
```

Please note that am accountSid is prefixed with AC (i.e. AC3265cbdh...)
and a serviceSid is prefixed with VA (i.e. VA3265cbdh...)

as hard-coded in the example shown in the link above from the docs

Answer (score 0):

Using Twilio with Golang I faced the same issue -
Here's How I resolved it ->

This was my function

```
func (app *Config) twilioSendOTP(phoneNumber string) (string, error) {
params := &twilioApi.CreateVerificationParams{}
params.SetTo(phoneNumber)
params.SetChannel("sms")
params.SetChannel("whatsapp")

resp, err := client.VerifyV2.CreateVerification(envServicesSid(), params)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

return *resp.Sid, nil
}

func (app *Config) twilioVerifyOTP(phoneNumber string, code string) error {

params := &twilioApi.CreateVerificationCheckParams{}
params.SetTo(phoneNumber)
params.SetCode(phoneNumber)

resp, err := client.VerifyV2.CreateVerificationCheck(envAccountSid(), params)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if *resp.Status != "approved"{
    return errors.New("not a valid code")
}
return nil
}
```

I made the mistake of using envAccountSid() *this function has my AccountSid that I am getting from .env* in my twilliosendOTP function I should replace it with envServicesSid() so that Twilio could verify my service. My new functions look like so -

```
func (app *Config) twilioSendOTP(phoneNumber string) (string, error) {
params := &twilioApi.CreateVerificationParams{}
params.SetTo(phoneNumber)
params.SetChannel("sms")
params.SetChannel("whatsapp")

resp, err := client.VerifyV2.CreateVerification(envServicesSid(), params)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

return *resp.Sid, nil
}

func (app *Config) twilioVerifyOTP(phoneNumber string, code string) error {

params := &twilioApi.CreateVerificationCheckParams{}
params.SetTo(phoneNumber)
params.SetCode(phoneNumber)

resp, err := client.VerifyV2.CreateVerificationCheck(envServicesSid(), params)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if *resp.Status != "approved"{
    return errors.New("not a valid code")
}
return nil
}
```

I hope this helped !!